# locationManager background battery life

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, core-motion

I have a question about saving battery when using locationManager. I was looking here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html
And here:
http://tumblr.twicetwice.net/post/47249353501/cllocationmanager-battery-saving-tips-and-best
And in many stackoverflow postings, but I can't use the most of these tips like `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`, because I need high accuracy updates very often, also in the background. Moreover I know that I can't use a timer in the background to get the location for example every 10 seconds. Now I want to stop getting location updates if I don't move for a specific time. And when I move again, I want to get updates again. I can't use 
`pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true`, because I don't want the user to put the app back into the foreground to update the location. Is there any other way to extend battery life when the app is in the background? I also searched for examples with CoreMotion, because I had the idea to turn off the GPS if I don’t move for a specific time and turn it on if the accelerometer detects a few steps. But I found out that this also doesn’t work in the background, or does anyone know a way to get this working? Are there maybe much better solutions for stop updating location when I don’t move and start updating location when I move while the app is in backgound? I would be thankful for any suggestions what I could do.

Btw: I’m pretty new in Swift so maybe there are very easy solutions that I don’t know and that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to stop getting location updates if I don't move for a specific time. And when I move again, I want to get updates again

You might be describing Visit monitoring. — But in general, asking for high accuracy locations continuously is very battery-expensive; that is why you're not supposed to do it unless the device is hooked to a source of power.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I can't use visit monitoring here, because as I know it only fires if I stay a few minutes in the specific location. I have a tableView which shows the locations that are less than 200 meters away from the user. Now if I'm 50 meters away from the location, I want to get a push notification. This all is working, but it has a lot battery consumption. I know that high accuracy location updates drains the battery. Because of this, I want to save a bit power when the user isn't moving, also when the app is in the background. Do you know if this is possible?